# Mongolab Authentication Failed Java

Tags: java, mongodb, authentication, mlab

I am trying to connect to MongoLab Database with Java client. But not able to authenticate with Mongolab server with following code:

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo("ds03456.mongolab.com", 51575);
DB db = mongo.getDB("sample");
boolean auth = db.authenticate("test", "test".toCharArray());
```

And i tried with same credentials with `Node.js` and it works fine:

```
var server = new Server('ds03456.mongolab.com', 51575);
var db = new Db('sample', server);
db.open({
      client.authenticate('test', 'test', function(err, success){
        //success = true.
      })
});
```

what could be the possible error?

Comment: Which version of java mongo driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Mongolab* is using `MongoDB 3.0+` and you're using version `2.0` deprecated classes to authenticate. This should work:

```
MongoClientURI clientURI = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://user:pass@address:port/dbname");
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(clientURI);
```